# How are $y=\sqrt{x}$ and $y^2=x$ different functions?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, examples-counterexamples, relations, radicals

Is 
$$
y = \sqrt{x}
$$

Any Different From 
$$
y^2 = x
$$

*If we square the function $y=\sqrt{x}$ , then don't we obtain $y^2=x$*

Which means these are same functions but they are not?

How does this happen?

Comment: There seems to be a typo because you wrote the same thing twice

Comment: it's not quite correct to call these functions without specifying a domain and codomain and taking a bit more care, i.e. defining the curves as the image set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $\{x,y \in \mathbb{R} \mid y^2 = x\}.$ That aside, this has nothing to do with the graphing of functions but instead the lack of injectivity when you square something without restricting to an appropriate branch first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function 
$$
y = \sqrt{x}
$$

Is defined only for *positive values of y.*

But The Function 
$$
y^2 = x
$$

Is defined for *all Real values of y.*

Moreover, you could see their graphs .

Comment: Are you sure that $y^2=x$ is a function?

Comment: Yes , if it is from *y to x* And No If it is from * x to y*.

Comment: In the given function $y=\sqrt{x}$ we have the function from $x$ to $y$. If after squaring you change it from $y$ to $x$ then you lose the essence.

Answer (score 4):

The relation $R=\{(x,y)|y^2=x\}$ is not function because for example $(4,2)\in R$ and $(4,-2)\in R$, but $2\neq-2$.

By the way, the relation $F=\{(x,y)|y=\sqrt{x},x\geq0,y\geq0\}$ is a function.

Comment: @Neo I don't understand your question. Sorry.  Multivariate functions is a function of course. In our case we say about function $x\rightarrow y$ of one variable $x$.

Comment: How is this not a function . It is a *Injective* function .

Comment: @Jonathann $R(4)=\{2,-2\}$. Is it injective?

Comment: But it is a function from *x to y* then why are you taking it from _y to x_ ?

Comment: @Jonathann $R$ is a relation from $x$ to $y$. See please better my post.

Comment: That's what even I am saying .

Comment: @Jonathann Did you see it from my post? Or you continue to say it without to see my post?

Comment: Even you wrote That it is a relation from *x to y* . But in the comment you wrote as if it was _from y to x._

Comment: Where I wrote it??? I think they are your words.

Comment: Nope . they are not my words .

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not.

Squaring both sides does not always work. Consider:

-2 and 2, they are not equal bit their squares are.

$$y^2=x$$ is the same as $$y = \pm \sqrt{x}$$

Comment: That's what I also knew . but it is just an example . Isn't there any generalized Proof for this ??

Comment: Proof by counterexample. If we claim that squaring an equation conserves equality, then finding any counterexample proves that squaring an equation does not necessarily conserve equality. This doesn't mean that lhs and rhs can never be never equal, they can!

Comment: What you are saying is *Disproving a statement by counterexample* !

Comment: http://www.math.toronto.edu/writing/Counterexample.pdf